# Identifying an 80's or 90's fantasy anime where they turn into animals

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was a kid I would rent a VHS of *Samurai Showdown – The Motion Picture* all the time. The tape had some awesome trailers for other anime videos (including *Neon Genesis*). There was one trailer in particular that I can still remember the music too but can not recall the name what so ever.

It was a **fantasy anime**, and I remember an **older person transforming into some type of saber-toothed cat** I believe, distributed by **A.D. Vision**. unfortunately that's all I can remember. I think others transformed into animals as well? Any possible leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's not a lot to go on. [Thundercats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT0ibo4QzI8)?

Comment: No it was high fantasy, and an anime movie, not a series. The frustrating part is I can find the other trailers (Evangelion, Dirty Pair, and Blood Reign: Curse of the Yoma to name a few) but not this one My guess is it was probably made around '93-'95.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you like you can just buy a copy from eBay and find out yourself (and then answer your own question, maybe). There's a copy of the VHS tape on sale right now for pretty cheap: http://m.ebay.com/itm/SAMURAI-SHODOWN-THE-MOTION-PICTURE-VHS-1994-MOVIE-BASED-ON-ARCADE-GAME-RARE-/231809892222

Comment: And not *Ranma 1/2* of course, right? That was a series but it certainly had people turning into animals.

Comment: Based on the title alone, I was so hoping this would be Animorphs... (and yes, I know that's not an anime)

Comment: i am looking for the same film, i believe each character could turn into a different animal. one of them could turn into a cheetah to run faster.

Answer (score 14):

*[Legend of Crystania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_Crystania)*! Found it on VHS while looking to get Samurai Showdown.

> *Legend of Crystania* (はじまりの冒険者たち レジェンド・オブ・クリスタニア *Hajimari no Bōkenshatachi: Rejendo obu Kurisutania?*, *First Adventurers: Legend of Crystania*) is a full-length Japanese animated motion picture. The film has been officially released on VHS and DVD in North America by ADV Films. It takes place in the same fantasy world as two other series, *Record of Lodoss War* and Rune Soldier, albeit on a different continent. It focuses on the land which Ashram sailed to after the Lodoss series, a world called Crystania which is under the rule of the animal gods. Ashram is king of the people of Marmo, the cursed island in *Record of Lodoss War*.
>
> In order to secure a future for his people, as well as his companion Pirotess, Ashram is forced to make a pact with an evil god called Barbas. Most of the plot in Crystania centres on Pirotess's (now called Sheru) quest to free Ashram from the evil Barbas, although the main character is called Prince Redon.
>
> Many new characters are introduced in the course of the film. Its sequel, the three-part original video animation (OVA) series *Legend of Crystania: The Chaos Ring*, goes into the story in further detail. These episodes were released on VHS and DVD in North America by ADV Films.

Comment: Congratulations! In about 48 hours, you will be able to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark below the voting buttons, and we highly recommend that you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Fruits Basket

Fruits Basket (Japanese: フルーツバスケット Hepburn: Furūtsu Basuketto?), sometimes abbreviated Furuba, or Fruba (フルバ?), is a Japanese shōjo manga series written and illustrated by Natsuki Takaya. It was serialized in the semi-monthly Japanese magazine Hana to Yume, published by Hakusensha, from 1998 to 2006. The series was also adapted into a 26-episode anime series, directed by Akitaro Daichi. The series tells the story of Tohru Honda, an orphan girl who, after meeting Yuki, Kyo, and Shigure Sohma, learns that twelve members of the Sohma family are possessed by the animals of the Chinese zodiac (十二支 Jūnishi?) and are cursed to turn into their animal forms when they are weak, stressed, or when they are embraced by anyone of the opposite sex that is not possessed by a zodiacal spirit. In the anime it is possible to transform through torso contact.